# PHP function to check if the number belongs to the interval

Tags: php, arrays

There is an array:

```
$bounds = array([0]=>array('lower'=>2,'upper'=>5), 
                [1]=>array('lower'=>0,'upper'=>3));
```

and a variable:

```
$val = 4;
```

Is there any PHP function that can say whether `$val` belongs to any interval defined by 'lower' and 'upper' bounds in `$bounds` array? In this example 4 belongs to the 1st interval [2; 5]. So, the answer should be 'true'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of any. You'll probably have to code it. Something like this will do:

```
function isFromInterval($bounds, $val) {
    foreach ($bounds as $value) {
        if ($val >= $value['lower'] && $val <= $value['upper']) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is a built-in function to do this.

However, you can do it with a `foreach` statement:

```
function check_interval($bounds, $val) {
   foreach ($bounds as $array) {
       if($array['lower'] <= $val && $array['upper'] >= $val)
           return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No.

You would have to make a loop for the array like this

```
$val    = 4;
$key_id = FALSE;

foreach($bounds as $key => $data){
    if($val <= $data['upper'] AND $val >= $data['lower']){
        $key_id = $key;
        break;
    }
}

if($key_id !== FALSE){
    //  found something
    //  $bounds[$key_id] is your result in the array
} else {
    // found nothing
}
```

As a function

```
function find_range($bounds=array(), $val=0, $return_key=TRUE){
    if(is_array($bounds) === FALSE){
        $bounds = array();
    }

    if(is_numeric($val) === FALSE){
        $val = 0;
    }

    if(is_bool($return_key) === FALSE){
        $return_key = TRUE;
    }

    $key_id = FALSE;

    foreach($bounds as $key => $data){
        if($val < $data['upper'] AND $val > $data['lower']){
            $key_id = $key;
            break;
        }
    }

    if($key_id !== FALSE){
        return ($return_key === TRUE ? $key_id : TRUE);
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can do:

```
$bounds = array(3=>array('lower'=>2,'upper'=>5), 
                4=>array('lower'=>0,'upper'=>3));

$val = 4;

foreach($bounds as $num => $bound){
    if(max($bound) >= $val && $val >= min($bound)){
        echo $num;
    }
}
```